# Can you please help modify this code to allow for Address and Zip Code Searches?

Tags: php, regex

I am still struggling immensely with these sets of rules below.

Rule: Any search text of 6 or more characters will be interpreted as an ID if one of the following is true:
 all characters are digits, or
 all digits except the third character, which is a D or N, or
 all digits except the third character except the 10th and 11th characters which are GG
 all digits except the third character, which is a D or N, and except the 10th and 11th characters which are GG

IDs will be reformatted as follows:
 If all digits, space inserted after 2nd digit (e.g., 67 00488780011)
 If 3rd character is D or N, no space after 2nd digit (e.g., 14N00339902009)
 If 10th and 11th characters are GG, two spaces before GG (e.g., 14 8725 GG0544)
 If 3rd character is D or N and 10th and 11th characters are GG, no space after 2nd digit but two spaces before GG (e.g., 14N0156 GG0390)

Here is the code I have so far.

```
function format($matches)
{
    return $matches[1][0].(strlen($matches[2][0])>0?$matches[2][0]:" ").$matches[3][0].(strlen($matches[4][0])>0?"  ".$matches[4][0]:"");
}

// CONSTRUCT A REGULAR EXPRESSION
$pattern
= '/'         // regex delimiter
. '('         // START of a capture group
. '\d{2}'     // exactly two digits
. ')'         // END of capture group
. '('         // START SECOND capture group
. '[\sND]?'     // letters "D" OR "N" in any order or number - This is optional
. ')'         // END SECOND capture group
. '('         // START THIRD capture group
. '\d*'       // any number of digits
. ')'         // END THIRD capture group
. '('         // START FOURTH capture group
. 'GG'        // the letters "GG" EXACTLY
. '[\d]*'     // any number of digits
. ')'         // END THIRD capture group
. '?'         // make the LAST capture group OPTIONAL
. '/'         // regex delimiter
;

// create an array of matches
preg_match_all($pattern, $_GET['id'], $matches);

// REFORMAT the array
$id = format($matches);
```

Now, all I would need is to add $id to my query as search filter.

The way this is supposed to work is that you enter an ID into the search box, hit GO. If that ID is valid, the ID is supposed to be reformated according to the rules above and displayed as a link.

The regex I have above does the reformating just fine but there are a few issues I have not been able to resolve.

1, only ID is supposed to be displayed per search if the code is working correctly. However, the search produces several IDs and the one you searched with happens to be one of them.
2, Users can also search by 5digit zip code and address such as 123 Gregory drive. After reformating with code above, users are no longer able to search with Address or zip code.

Something is definitely wrong with the code but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance for being patient with me and for your assistance.

```
$patterns = array(
    '/^(\d\d)(\d{4,})$/',
    '/^(?=.{6,}$)(\d\d[\dDN]\d*)(GG\d*)$/'
);

$replacements = array( '$1 $2', '$1  $2' );

$_GET['id'] = $id;

$id = preg_replace( $patterns, $replacements, $_GET['id'] )
```

Comment: @MikeM, thank you very for your assistance. For your last question(s), please excuse me for saying this but I am not sure if addresses and zip codes need formating. What I do know is that before we formated the ID with the code I posted, users were able to search with zip code and give that one single zip code or some cases a few more related zip codes. Same with addresses. Since the ID was reformatted with code above, searching with zip codes and addresses don't work anymore. They either don't find the address or zip code or they find a range of them.

Comment: Since you are limited by how much you can type, I ran out of space.

Example of wrong zip code search is now you get a range of say 501100 to 53001 when searching with say 53012. Same with addresses. I am sure there is some tweaking to be done with the code. I am just stumped and users are not very happy right now. As for the 10th and 11th digit, I think they are wrong. The idea is whenever the code finds GG in ID, insert 2 spaces before the GG. If all digits, insert one single space after 2 digits, if the characters are either N D after 2 digits and no rest are digits, no spaces.

Comment: @MikeM, excellent points indeed. Do I use preg_replace in place of preg_match?

Maybe, a conditional if?

Any idea how the code above could be modified to handle the great points you made about zip code and address?

Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated following comment feedback:

The following will perform the required replacements, as far as I can understand them:

```
$patterns = array(
    '/^(\d\d)(\d{4,})$/',
    '/^(?=.{6,}$)(\d\d)(\d*)(GG\d*)$/',
    '/^(?=.{6,}$)(\d\d[DN]\d*)(GG\d*)$/'
); 

$replacements = array( '$1 $2', '$1 $2  $3', '$1  $2' );    

$id = preg_replace( $patterns, $replacements, $_GET['id'] );
```

The first regular expression, `/^(\d\d)(\d{4,})$/`, will match if the string contains 6 or more digits.

The second expression will match if the string contains 6 or more characters where all are digits except that after the second character GG may appear once in place of two digits.

The third expression will match if the string contains 6 or more characters where all are digits except the third character which is D or N, and except that after the third character GG may appear once in place of two digits.

If the string does not match either expression, no replacements are made.

In the `$replacements` array items, `$1` refers to the digits in the first capture group, `$2` to the second, and `$3` the third.

You may want to trim whitespace from the input before passing it to `preg_replace`.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts and patience @MikeM. This doesn't work, man this is hard. I know why the ID doesn't work. They lied to me that GG is the 10th and 11th characters. One of th IDs I just tested with is 12 characters long and GG are 7th and 8th characters, not 10th and 11th. I have taken so much of your time but is it possible to not worry about the position of GG and just ensure that 2 spaces are inserted before the first G. That will take care of 2nd G. I still don't know why address and zip don't work either. Your code seems very solid.

Comment: @Kenny. Updated the second regular expression so that GG can appear anywhere after the third character. If you show your query code it may become clear why address and zip code searches don't work.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your patience. Address and zipcode are working perfectly now but now the ID is not. Just so I am not going crazy, I posted the latest code at the top below the original code I posted. Just out of curiosity, what is dDN?

I know DN but the small d before DN, I would like to know.

Comment: @Kenny. `\d` means a digit 0-9. Therefore `[\dDN]` means that the character can be a digit or D or N. Looking at your question edit: you need to remove the `$_GET['id'] = $id;` line.

Comment: I did but still no love. Everything is working great except the ID, just for starters, this is the ID I am currently testing with:

330022GG0587, again IDs could, and do get longer but I am getting any space after 33 and no spaces before GG. As a result, search results says no record found. If you add the spaces manually as indicated, it works.

Comment: @Kenny. With the above code, a `$_GET['id']` of `330022GG0587` gives an `$id` of `330022  GG0587`, i.e. with two spaces before the `G`. Note that `$_GET['id']` must not contain leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: right, it should also give a single space after 2 digits. Please remember that if all digits, a space needs to be inserted after first 2 digits. That holds true even there are GG somewhere within the digits. For instance, 330022GG0587, when reformatted, should now be 33 0022  GG0587.

Notice the single space after 33 and the doulbe space before GG. That's probably why it isn't working and I am not sure how difficutl it is to fix. Hopefully, it doesn't after the ones that are currently working.
Thanks again for all your help and more importantly, your patience. I can learn from you.

Comment: Sorry sir @MikeM. Again, many thanks for your patience and assistance.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you @MikeM. You have really, really saved me.

I don't know how to thank you. However, the Good Lord will reward you for me. I will keep your information for future if I have to freelance you for something. Thank you very sir. It is working now as expected, YEA!!